# Exception when trying to spy with Mockito

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I want to spy on my CustomerService in my Junit tests. I found this perfect answer on how to inject my spy into my test without AOP: [How to Mock, Spy, and Fake Spring Beans](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-mock-spring-bean-version-2)

This is my @profile I use for my test

```
@Bean
@Primary
public CustomerService getCustomerService(CustomerService customerService) {
    return Mockito.spy(customerService);
}
```

When I then run my test the whole spring application context crashes with this exception:

```
Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@5579bb86] to prepare test instance [CustomerControllerTest@451f3f66]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:183) ~[spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:123) ~[spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228) ~[spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230) [spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249) [spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89) [spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193) [spring-test-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getCustomerService' defined in class path resource [ServiceSpyConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.AssertionError: java.beans.IntrospectionException: type mismatch between indexed read and indexed write methods: callback
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
... 134 common frames omitted
 Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: java.beans.IntrospectionException: type mismatch between indexed read and indexed write methods: callback
at java.beans.IndexedPropertyDescriptor.<init>(IndexedPropertyDescriptor.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
at java.beans.Introspector.processPropertyDescriptors(Introspector.java:657) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetPropertyInfo(Introspector.java:553) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:428) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:262) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:204) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:278) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:177) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyDescriptors(BeanWrapperImpl.java:236) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1368) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.filterPropertyDescriptorsForDependencyCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1347) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1209) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
... 143 common frames omitted
  Caused by: java.beans.IntrospectionException: type mismatch between indexed read and indexed write methods: callback
at java.beans.IndexedPropertyDescriptor.findIndexedPropertyType(IndexedPropertyDescriptor.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
at java.beans.IndexedPropertyDescriptor.setIndexedReadMethod(IndexedPropertyDescriptor.java:217) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
at java.beans.IndexedPropertyDescriptor.<init>(IndexedPropertyDescriptor.java:462) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
... 156 common frames omitted
```

Anyone know how to make this run?

Comment: Which JDK are you using ?

Comment: @sol4me oracle jdk 1.8.0_77

Comment: Looking at the stacktrace it seems that there's a type mismatch for the `customerService` field in your `ServiceSpyConfiguration` class, could you please paste it?

Comment: As a sidenote : have you tried naming the field you want to autowire and the method providing the bean with the same name (i.e. if the field is named `customerService`, name the `@Bean`-annotated method `customerService` too)?

Comment: @francescoforesti The getCustomerService method is the only method in ServiceSpyConfiguration and I tried naming it just customerService and it gives the same error

Comment: ask yourself again why you need to do such thing in unit test. It is rarely correct

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My problem was caused by methods annotated by `@Transcational`. Probably when you have them you are mocking/spying proxy object not real bean. You can probably spy this bean as-is but rather with method described in "Spy on a Spring Bean Proxied by Spring AOP" of [How to Mock, Spy, and Fake Spring Beans](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-mock-spring-bean-version-2)